# Umbraco site redirecting to live URL automatically

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have just download working umbraco site from live server when i am trying to run it on localhost it automatically redirecting to live server location not running on my localhost. My umbraco version is 7.1. Database is also on local.

Comment: Do you have any redirect plugins / functionality that is working with absolute urls? Have you any entries in your hosts file that may be intercepting? Did you change the DSN settings in web.config?

Comment: No nothing like that. I was using seo fridnly url package but i was commented it in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running it from WebMatrix? I think there is an option to publish straight to Azure in there?

Comment: sorry I just re-read what you wrote. If you were to flush you dns cache and restart your browser would that make any effect?

Comment: Yes i am using webmatrix but no option to publish to azure.